# The helper "action" is not defined

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony2 framework and I am having error in my project.

The error am having is this: The helper "action" is not defined. I created a controller function, in the function I added some code for building a form and the render function to render it through a template.

Now am trying to display the form in my index.html.php page by include the form template in the index page, but am having this display: The helper "action" is not defined.

```
public function formAction(Request $request)
{
    // $task = new Task();
    // $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    // $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)->add('task', 'text')->add('dueDate', 'date')->add(
        'save',
        'submit',
        array('label' => 'Create Task')
    )->getForm();

    return $this->render('HarriseqBundle:Main:login-form.html.php', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html

Comment: my form controller code:public function formAction(Request $request) {
  //$task = new Task();
  //$task->setTask('Write a blog post');
  //$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
  
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
  ->add('task','text')
  ->add('dueDate','date')
  ->add('save', 'submit', array('label'=>'Create Task'))
  ->getForm();
  
  return $this->render('HarriseqBundle:Main:login-form.html.php', array('form'=>$form->createView()));
 }

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Michael Sivolobov for editing my post.

Comment: Hello, can you show code of login-form.html.php

Comment: print $view['action']->render(new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference('HarriseqBundle:Main:form'));

Comment: It's wrong, try this `<?php echo $view['form']->start($form) ?>
<?php echo $view['form']->widget($form) ?>
<?php echo $view['form']->end($form) ?>`. Remove your `print $view['action']`

Answer (score 0):

You problem in login-form.html.php. Because `print $view['action']->render(new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerReference('HarriseqBundle:Mai‌​n:form'));` is not correct code. Please, using this tutorial to create forms http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Error isn't into controller's action but into form render

```
echo $view['action']
```

isn't right way to accomplish what you're trying to do while

```
echo $view['form']
```

does

So, basically, edit your code (`HarriseqBundle:Main:login-form.html.php`) as follows

```
<?php echo $view['form']->start($form) ?>
<?php echo $view['form']->widget($form) ?>
<?php echo $view['form']->end($form) ?>
```

or

```
<?php 
  echo $view['form']->start($form);
  echo $view['form']->widget($form);
  echo $view['form']->end($form);
```

What `start`, `widget`, end `methods` do?

`start()` method will render the starting tag `<form>` of your form object (so basically you can pass it some parameters such submitting method)

`end()` method will render the ending tag `</form>`

`widget()` will render all elements of your form (if applied to whole form) or, if you specify form element as a parameter, only that element

Also take a look to `rest()` method

Comment: echo $view['form']->start($form)

Comment: But it is showing another error message: Undefined variable form

Comment: @charly: could you update your question with `var_dump($view)`? I'm sure that if names you used are correct, this method should works

Comment: But the page is coming up blank.